# Google Analytics - IP Address as Website URL

Tags: google-analytics

Anybody ever successfully used an IP address as the website URL for a profile in Google Analytics?

See my post in the Google Analytics Forum also:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=4551af07a8fce6ac&hl=en

Comment: Is this ip address visible from outside your LAN??  i.e. can you go http://999.888.777.666 from a browser anywhere and get your site?

Comment: Yes you can get to the site using the IP in any browser

Answer (score 2):

You can track the data in Google by adding the ip address along with the port number as  website url.