# Using Website IP address to set up Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to set up Google analytics tracking on my site. Right now it's in QA phase, site is not officially launched with vanity URL yet. So we are using Site IP address to enter in web property URL.

However, we do not get any data in GA, I wonder if it';s because we are using IP rather than url.

I see a post asking the same question but no answers yet: [Google Analytics - IP Address as Website URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407449/google-analytics-ip-address-as-website-url)

Comment: Please show your google analytics javascript code.  If you are using your planned final domain name there in the code, you will not get any tracking associated with it when accessing the site via IP address.